# Fibonacci sequence in nature, truth or just wishful thinking?

Tags: structural-biology, development

I'm reading a bit on the Fibonacci sequence in nature, be it the golden ratio or the golden spiral forming over and over again in biological structures, and then I came across [this online article](http://www.lhup.edu/~dsimanek/pseudo/fibonacc.htm) by Donald E. Simanek, refuting a lot of these observations as merely optimistic 'flim flam'.

So which is true?

Does the Fibonacci sequence have a place in nature or is it all just a case of vigorously looking for anything that resembles a correlation?

Comment: Search for Vi Hart on Youtube. She makes educational and oddly entertaining math videos and she has one about plants displaying both Fibonacci and Lucas numbers as a way to maximize sunlight reception by the leaves.

Comment: I mean, I'm curious too, and Vi's video is all I've heard about this correlation. I'm not asserting she's right, just that you might enjoy it. The video is called Doodling in Math: Spirals, Fibonacci, and Being a Plant.

Comment: Thanks I'll give them a watch, I remember watching an entertaining one she did on the nature of infinity I think.

Comment: Didn't the Fibonacci sequence arise when modeling the dynamics of rabbit populations?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember, Fibonacci patterns emerge in plants from hormone gradients. I.e. an apical meristem forms a leaf where the auxin concentration is highest, and already existing leafs lower auxin concentration, leading to some negative feedback.

See e.g.
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1360138507000581

or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllotaxis

Comment: I'm aware of how these patterns are seemingly formed, what the question is asking is whether these patterns are indeed examples of proper mathematical Fibonacci sequences or if they merely bear resemblance.

Comment: The pattern forming processes generate a fibonnachi pattern, but there are other processes that occur as well.